# Does "deep exhale" fit into this sentence example?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

(Ex. These loose leaf papers could be easily blown away, even by a kid's **deep exhale**.) I know that if I put >even by a kid who is deeply exhaling<, instead of what is in my example, the sentence would be correct, but is my example wrong?

Comment: Have you looked to see whether dictionaries include 'exhale' as a noun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Exhale](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exhale) is a verb; [exhalation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exhalation) is the corresponding noun.